# Color coding weather data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a weather file with precipitation and temperature and I have coded it in a way that the entire data set gets plotted into four categories: Cool and Wet, Cool and Dry, Warm and Wet and, Warm and Dry. I was wondering if it is possible to introduce a specific color for each category. I am unable to do it

Year    rain    temp
87  91.4    10.4
88  133.3   10.9
89  106 10.64
90  59.12   12.6
91  99  9.9
92  145.36  10.51
93  133.3   10.89
94  133 10.8
95  122 10.09
96  162 8.7
97  250 11.06
98  133 10.5
99  27  10.4
0   138 11
1   182 12.8
2   138 10
3   129 10.3
4   142 12.5
5   114 13.3
6   102 10.3
7   193 11.8
8   242 10.6
9   139 10.1
10  80.41   4.05
11  56.64   11.1
12  58.24   11.3
13  141.26  11.56
14  76.7    10.3
15  87.28   10.4
16  147.7   13.2
17  154.8   11.8
    126.3390323 10.76774194

I coded it as :

```
library(ggplot2)
setwd('C:/Users/nchatterjee2/Desktop')
data <- read.csv("Fall.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",row.names=NULL, fill = T)
limit_humid <- 128
limit_warm <- 11
head(data)

    ggplot(data, aes(x = temp, y = rain)) +
      geom_text(aes(label = Year))+
      geom_vline(xintercept = limit_warm) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = limit_humid) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and Wet")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = min(data$temp), y = max(data$rain)) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and Wet")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = max(data$temp), y = max(data$rain)) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and Dry")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = min(data$temp), y = min(data$rain)) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and Dry")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = max(data$temp), y = min(data$rain)) +
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
      ) 

      labs(x = 'Average Temperature (°C)',
           y = 'Cumulative precipitation (mm)')+ theme_light()







    library(ggplot2)
    setwd('C:/Users/nchatterjee2/Desktop')
    data <- read.csv("Fall.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",row.names=NULL, fill = T)
    limit_humid <- 128
    limit_warm <- 11
    head(data)

    ggplot(data, aes(x = temp, y = rain)) +
      geom_text(aes(label = Year))+
      geom_vline(xintercept = limit_warm) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = limit_humid) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and Wet")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = min(data$temp), y = max(data$rain)) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and Wet")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = max(data$temp), y = max(data$rain)) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and Dry")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = min(data$temp), y = min(data$rain)) +
      annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and Dry")', size = 3, parse = T,
               x = max(data$temp), y = min(data$rain)) +
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
      ) 

      labs(x = 'Average Temperature (°C)',
           y = 'Cumulative precipitation (mm)')+ theme_light()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where I add a field to the data and map color to that:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(temp >= limit_warm & rain >= limit_humid ~ "Warm and Wet",
                              temp >= limit_warm  ~ "Warm and Dry",
                              rain >= limit_humid ~ "Cool and Wet",
                              TRUE ~ "Cool & Dry")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = temp, y = rain, color = category)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Year))+
    geom_vline(xintercept = limit_warm) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = limit_humid) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and Wet")', size = 3, parse = T,
             x = min(data $temp), y = max(data $rain), hjust = 0) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and Wet")', size = 3, parse = T,
             x = max(data $temp), y = max(data $rain), hjust = 1) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and Dry")', size = 3, parse = T,
             x = min(data $temp), y = min(data $rain), hjust = 0) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and Dry")', size = 3, parse = T,
             x = max(data $temp), y = min(data $rain), hjust = 1) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(
    plot.background = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

If you want to replace the "a" in the legend with points, it can be done by hiding the text legend, adding a dummy transparent `geom_point`, and overriding the point legend size:

```
ggplot(aes(x = temp, y = rain, color = category)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Year), show.legend = F)+
    ...
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=4, alpha = 1))) +
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much. When I try this code, I get the error: Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : object 'temp' not found

Comment: I named the data `df` when I pulled it in, instead of `data like your example. I've renamed as `data` in the answer now, hopefully that fixes it.